# serial protocol patterns

Tags: serial-communication, protocol

I am reversing a serial 232 protocol and I found these pattern in the data.

```
E5 A7 CD 01 00 
79 .. .. 40
00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
```

follows some recording and expected approx results

```
A=~-10 B=0 C=0 D=~-85.9
E5 A7 CD 01 00 79 31 0A 79 35 0A 79 36 0A 40 0F 24 50 05 9B B1 94 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
8F E5 A7 CD 01 00 79 31 0A 79 35 0A 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
2B E5 A7 CD 01 00 79 31 0A 79 35 0A 79 36 0A 40 0F 24 50 05 9B D8 A4 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
C6 E5 A7 CD 01 00 79 31 0A 5B 00 00 79 35 0A 79 36 0A 40 0F 24 50 05 9C 01 CC 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
18 E5 A7 CD 01 00 79 31 0A 79 35 0A 79 36 0A 
B4 E5 A7 CD 01 00 79 31 0A 79 35 0A 79 36 0A 40 0F 24 50 05 9C 28 DC 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
4F E5 A7 CD 01 00 79 31 0A 79 35 0A 79 36 0A
79 36 4A 40 0F 24 50 05 9C 4F EC 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
79 36 4E 40 0F 24 50 05 9C 63 74 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
79 36 0E 40 0F 24 50 05 9C 76 FC 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
79 36 0E 40 0F 24 50 05 9C 8A 84 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
79 36 0E 40 0F 24 50 05 9C B1 94 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
30 E5 A7 CD 01 00 79 31 0E 40 0F 24 50 05 9C D7 DC FF 9C 00 79 36 0E 40 0F 24 50 05 9C D8 A4 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
CB E5 A7 CD 01 00 79 31 0E 40 0F 24 50 05 9D 01 FF 9C 00 07 00 01 00 90 02 35 00 00 79 36 0E 40 0F 24 50 05 9D 01 CC 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
79 36 0E 40 0F 24 50 05 9D 28 DC 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
79 36 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 9D 4F EC 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
79 36 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 9D 63 74 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
79 36 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 9D 8A 20 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
79 36 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 9D 9E 0C 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
79 36 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 9D B1 30 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
72 E5 A7 CD 01 00 79 31 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 9D C3 F0 02 4C
79 36 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 9D C4 B8 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21 05 0A
82 79 36 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 9D D8 40 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
A9 E5 A7 CD 01 00 79 31 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 9E 00 A0 05 05 14 00 F6 00 64 00 5A 00 00 79 35 0F 40 4F 05 00 63 88 0F A0 0F A0 0F A0 00 00 00 00 00 00 24 50 05   9E 01
FB E5 A7 CD 01 00 79 31 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 9E 14 28 06 DC 05 94 01 0E 00 5B 00 1E 00 00 79 35 0F 40 4F 06 DC 00 63 88 0F A0 0F A0 0F A0 00 00 00 00 00 00 24   50 05 9E 14 8C 07 0A 79 36 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 9E 14 F0 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
79 36 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 9E 28 78 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
32 E5 A7 CD 01 00 79 31 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 9E 3B 38 07 68 05 60 01
CE E5 A7 CD 01 00 79 31 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 9E 4E C0 05 5F 79 36 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 9E 4F 88 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
99 45 00 CE 00 34 FF FE 00 00 07 79 36 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 9E 63 10 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
79 36 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 9E 76 98 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
4B 00 9F 00 24 00 02 00 00 79 36 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 9E 8A 20 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
79 36 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 9E 9D A8 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
D7 E5 A7 CD 01 00 79 31 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 9E B0 68 00 6E 02 9D 00 7E 00 1B 00 79 36 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 9E B1 30 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21

A=~3 B=~573 C=~11 =~-1.5

79 36 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 9E C4 B8 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21 05 0E E5 A7 CD 01 00 79 31 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 9E D7 78 00 02 45 00 6E 00 1B   00 00 00 00 79 36 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 9E D8 40 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
79 35 0F 40 4F 00 0B 00 13 88 0F A0 0F A0 0F A0 00 00 00 00 00 00 24 50 05 9F 01
79 36 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 9F 14 F0 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
79 36 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 9F 28 78 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
79 36 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 9F 4F 88 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
6A E5 A7 CD 01 00 79 31 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 9F 62 48 02 48 79 36 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 9F 63 10 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
EB 79 36 2F 40 4F 24 50 05 9F 76 98 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
C1 E5 A7 CD 01 00 79 31 2F 40 4F 24 50 05 9F 89 58 05 FA 05 5D 01 79 36 2F 40 4F 24 50 05 9F 8A 20 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21

A=~290 B=~1506 C=~28 D=~-1.6

79 36 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 9F 9D A8 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
79 36 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 9F B1 30 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
79 36 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 9F D8 40 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
AB E5 A7 CD 01 00 79 31 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 A0 00 A0 0A 79 35 0F 40 4F 0A
79 36 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 A0 14 F0 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
79 36 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 A0 28 78 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
D0 E5 A7 CD 01 00 79 31 2F 40 4F 24 50 05 A0 4E C0 B3 79 35 2F 40 4F 79 36 2F 40 4F 24 50 05 A0 4F 88 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
46 46 00 63 88 0F A0 0F A0 0F A0 00 00 00 00 00 00 24 50 05 A0 62 AC 07 79 36 2F 40 4F 24 50 05 A0 63 10 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
79 36 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 A0 76 98 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
3F 00 9D 00 23 00 02 00 00 79 36 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 A0 8A 20 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
00 79 36 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 A0 9D A8 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
79 36 0F 40 4F 24 50 05 A0 B1 30 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
```

Any advice to understand how data is structured?

Comment: what is the data supposed to represent? Do you know the approximate values?

Comment: here to you some raw data with approximate data

    A=~-10 B=0 C=0 D=~-85.9
    E5 A7 CD 01 00 79 31 0A 79 35 0A 79 36 0A 40 0F 24 50 05 9B B1 94 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
    8F E5 A7 CD 01 00 79 31 0A 79 35 0A 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 23 00 22 00 22 00 22 00 21
    2B E5 A7 CD 01 00 79 31 0A 79 35 0A 79 36 0A 40 0F 24 50 05 9B

Comment: Ok probably it is better to edit the main question.

Comment: yes, please do.

Comment: I tried to do my best.

Comment: Ok, I edited a third time adding a couple more of expected values.. Values are not exact.

Comment: thanks! hopefully with the new data it will be easier.